# Python symlink to python3

Tags: python, unix, symlink, apple-m1

So I'm setting up my default variables in a new MacBook M1 and for some reason, my symlink doesn't seem to work.

Why is the following behaviour happening? The symlink from `python` to `python3` gets lost somehow. `/Users/overflow/Documents/tools` is part of my `PATH` variable.

```sh
$ type python
python is /Users/overflow/Documents/tools/python

$ python -V
Python 2.7.16

$ ls -lah /Users/overflow/Documents/tools/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 overflow  staff    16B  6 Oct 18:48 /Users/overflow/Documents/tools/python -> /usr/bin/python3

$ /usr/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.8.9

$ echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
/Users/overflow/Documents/tools
/Users/overflow/Documents/Dropbox/productivity/bin
/Users/overflow/Documents/tools/confluent-6.1.0/bin
/Users/overflow/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin
/Users/overflow/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin
/Users/overflow/bin
/usr/local/bin
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Comment: some system may still use Python 2 to run some functions and sometimes changing symlink may crush system. Better use command `python3` or `python3.8` to run Python 3

Comment: maybe you have other command `python` in current folder and it may run this command instead of `/Users/overflow/Documents/tools/python` . Maybe you have path `.` on `PATH` so it may run command `python` like `./python`

Comment: Maybe it's an alias or function... run 'type python'.. it will give you a better answer than 'which' does.

Comment: I didn't know about `type` command, it's awesome! - I've just replaced the `which` statement with a `type` one. Also added my `PATH` there

Comment: you did not show the result of : which python

Comment: The link you made is on python is on the directory which contains python or on python3 exe : what is important is the PATH contents which should give directory containing exe. Also check that there is not a alias python.

Comment: I removed the result of `which` but it was showing the same as `type`. Now, the `PATH` variable contains `/Users/overflow/Documents/tools`, which is the directory containing the "exe" you mention that is the link I've just created. I'm not sure I get what you mean by that tbh.

Comment: Can we know the type of the shell with version? `bash` or `zsh`. I'm not sure if that would help in particular but it can help in narrowing down the search.

Comment: Run `hash -r` and try again. It clears a cache in shell.

Comment: I noticed you have home-brew, so you can home-brew pyenv and set your global pyenv to whatever version you need. I use it to run 3.10.0 at the moment on my M1

Comment: `hash -r` didn't solve the issue. I would like to avoid using python managers and use the default one.

Comment: While I'm not sure why this is happening, might I suggest using an alias instead of a symlink? Personally, I use `alias python=python3.9` and `alias pip=pip3.9` in my `.zshrc`. [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/320996/1014459) question may be of interest.

Answer (score 5):

I can give you some general troubleshooting tips and a band-aid that can replace a symlink.

```
$(which python) -V
```

This should get you the version for python3.

Other thing worth checking:

```
which python2
```

This should point to some standard location, `/usr/bin/python2` for example. If it isn't pointed there, might be worth understanding why.

In general, Macs have some quirks. The fact that a new MacBook M4 ships with Python2 as the default is a smell that you probably shouldn't try to overwrite the default value, and for whatever reason it doesn't seem to want you to.

Simple answer: set an alias.

```
echo 'alias python="python3"' >> ~/.zshrc && source;
```

This will work for you and should not interfere with any potential other systems.

Better answer:

As others have described, create a virtual environment and `source venv/bin/activate`.

Comment: +1  to 'alias python="python3"` if `args[0]` ends with 3, you will get a Python3 interpreter no matter what `venv` is set to.

Answer (score 5):

For macOs 13 (Ventura)

Required install python3 first then set an alias for python that link to python3.

```
echo 'alias python="python3"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc;
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the path is not being utilized, it is being overridden by a shell alias. This can be confirmed by typing `set | grep python`

If you are using [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/):

Try: `/usr/bin/python3 -m venv python3.8.9`

The common MacOS python managers are:

1. [pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz)

List installs using `pythonz list`

Change using: `/usr/bin/python3 -m venv python3.8.9`

2. [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew)

List installs `pythonbrew list`

Use `pythonbrew switch 3.8.9` to move to the new version.

3. [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Claims to use only $PATH. Included for completeness, but just in case

List installs `pyenv versions`

Use `pyenv global 3.8.9` to move to the new version.

---

To remove any of these remove the appropriate line from your  `~/.bashrc` or  `~/.zshrc` file.

You can locate the line with `grep ~/.bashrc python`.

Comment: `set | grep python` doesn't return anything and neither of those three python managers is installed.

Comment: `type python` would print `python is an alias for ...` if OP had an alias set. Since they supplied `type python` output in the question, I think we can safely say they do **not** have an alias set.

Comment: @thisisrandy, That is correct. The type output was not there when I started the answer.  In that case it, is most likely the python virtual environment.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is not specific to Mac, but on a `.deb` based system you want:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```